# Unable to use the Enter-key on a file input's label to open the file browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a file input, with a label. I wish to be able to open the file browser in four different ways:

1. Clicking the file input button
2. Tabbing to the file input button and hitting enter
3. Clicking the file input label
4. Tabbing to the file input label and hitting enter

However, only options 1-3 work out of the box? Is this a bug, or an intended feature? I'm currently working on FireFox v106.0.5

Are there any solutions out there that rely solely on HTML/CSS, or is JS required to fix the issue?

```html
<label for="file_input" tabindex="0">
  Label
</label>
<input type="file" id="file_input">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally, the `input` opens a dialog when it receives click or enter.

The `label` itself does not open a dialog, but when clicked (or tapped), it can [passes the focus to its associated input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label), and a dialog is opened as a result.

It does not do the same when it receives enter, thus the situation 4 in your question does not work.

This is because the purpose of this design is to increase the hit size for the associated `input`, especially for user on a touch-screen device.

So to answer the question, it is an intended feature.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I want to style the button for uploading files, but styling the input-element itself is quite tricky, so I opted to style the label instead, and hide the actual input-element. Now I have the issue that users with screen-readers (or just using the keyboard to tab through) can't actually bring up the file-menu...

Answer (score 0):

Th3o4oR - I encountered a similar accessibility issue and was able to overcome it using on key up event on the button. Pressing the enter key when focussed on the button will open the file browser dialog.

```
<input type="file" id="file-input"/>

<button type="button" onkeyup="myFunction(event)">Button</input>

<script>
function myFunction(evemt) {

    console.log("onkeyup: ", event.key);
    
    //get the file input element
    const fileInput = document.getElementById("file-input");
    
    if (event.key === "Enter" && fileInput) {
        // click the file input element to open the file dialog
        fileInput.click();
    }
            
}
</script>
```