# Unable to trigger input event from label element with keyboard

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, tabindex

When I click the `label` with the mouse I get the file browser popup as expected. But when I use the keyboard and **tab** to the label and hit *enter* I don't.

```js
<>
  <label className="button" htmlFor="fileUploadInput" tabIndex={0}>
    Upload File
  </label>
  <input id="fileUploadInput" type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
</>
```

To create a custom file input button, the `label` has all the fancy styling and is visible. The `input` has the style below.

```css
input {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the enter key is not a trigger for the file input. So you're going to have to handle the enter key event and trigger the popup yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to use the Enter-key on a file input's label to open the file browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74453390/unable-to-use-the-enter-key-on-a-file-inputs-label-to-open-the-file-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments there is no native way to handle this. I ended up creating a `ref` for the `input`. And added a `onKeyUp` event on the `label` which allowed to programmaticly open the file browser dialog when the ***enter*** key was clicked.

```js
const inputRef = useRef(null);

const handleLabel = (e) => {
  if (e.key !== "Enter" || inputRef.current === null) return;
  inputRef.current.click();
};

<>
  <label
    className="button"
    htmlFor="fileUploadInput"
    tabIndex={0}
    onKeyUp={handleLabel}
  >
    Upload File
  </label>
  <input
    ref={inputRef}
    id="fileUploadInput"
    type="file"
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
</>
```